# How Can i retrieve pages metadata using RESTAPI

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

While crawling the metadata using SharePoint connector via REST API we are unable to form the Pages content.

I have the site contents name like pages, under the pages I have totally around 40 pages, in that 40 I need to form the request of one particular pages.

Can u please assist on the same.

Which approach shall I follow?

```
GetFileByServerRelativeUrl

GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl

https://www.sitename.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')
```

Comment: You need to use `/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items` endpoint

Comment: Thank you. Working fine. i need to capture the metadata of inside the pages. how can i do that. 


{
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.PagesItem",
   
            "odata.id": "Web/Lists(guid'e742e0aa-ff77-42b2-9660-6aaa975e03ab')/Items(6)",
   
            "odata.etag": "\"35\"",
   
            "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'e742e0aa-ff77-42b2-9660-6aaa975e03ab')/Items(6)",
   
            "Id": 6,
   
            "Title": null,
   
            "ID": 6,
   
            "FileRef": "/sites/pnp/Pages/atozindex.aspx"
        },